# EC2 / LAMP with a temporary File System

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filesystems, apache2

Ok - this is a weird one.

I've now got my domain pointing to a new EC2 instance running our website, but initially I thought I had some issues with file permissions, has now turned to be where the web service is holding a completely separate file system layer on top of the one already in place.

What do I mean? Any file I upload to the site, or that I create using `file_put_contents()` is not accessible if I SSH in to the server. Completely invisible.  This is a big problem for me, as I have got jobs on cron on the root user which is designed to look for these files and perform whatever jobs it needs to.

If I restart the apache2 service - the files that had been created in that session are reset, as if they were never there in the first place.  Even if I don't restart the session - I have no way of accessing these file again - though it would probably only work if I redirect it as a file download.  As far as PHP is concerned, they are in `scandir()`, true for `file_exists()` etc.

Has anyone had any familiarity with this and know how I can disable it so it behaves as normal?  On my research, it sounds similar to EFS, but have no idea to turn that off, let alone turn it on.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you create your stack in the first place? 
Do you mind showing the configuration you have for your EC2 as an image?

Comment: It's just a small t2.micro / Ubuntu 18.04 / PHP 7.3... Pretty loaded question, I want to provide with as much information as I can because this issue is pretty important, but not sure what's relevant... But as far as the step-by-step process to create i, didn't do anything but the defaults really.

Comment: Very strange that is. 
I would recomend you to try to upload one very big file. Check the disk partition 's available size before and after.
It will help you confirm that the file is actually written down somewhere on that disk. Do check available space again after restarting apache. That will confirm if the files are temporary or not

Comment: Confirmed: While uploading a file failed (at least now proof of that is just something I need to fix the configuration for) - I did run a process several times which uses `file_put_contents()` - this did increase the memory used count as expected, and immediately after running `service apache2 restart` - this figure was reset.

Comment: By "Memory" you mean "Disk space" right? Anyways, I think you will find better luck solving this problem on general PHP / Apache / Server questions
I am not aware of any specific AWS configuration can lead to this issue

Comment: I do, yeah. Sound - well - I'll still leave this here - hopefully will get a passer-by who's crossed similar paths who can help lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191138/discussion-between-jester-and-qkhanhpro).

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved!

Apache was configured to use a private */tmp* directory.  Everything explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/961237/ec2-lamp-with-a-temporary-file-system/961912#961912).

Cheers.